# INSERT INTO while SELECT ... FOR UPDATE

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, innodb, deadlock

I'm having trouble with what I presume is a deadlock. I need to insert a row in a table but beforehand a lock is placed on rows in this table using `FOR UPDATE`. I use the `FOR UPDATE` statement to prevent users from inserting another row before them having completed a certain action.

I've seen a question where something similar was happening and it seemed to be the case because of the auto-incrementing `id`. I'm just having a huge struggle of trying to find a solution.

**psuedo-code**

```
const connection = await database.getConnection();
  try {
    await connection.beginTransaction();
    
    // check if a certain user already has an active row.
    const [active] = await connection.query(`SELECT * FROM trades
              WHERE user_id = 1 AND state = 1 FOR UPDATE`);
    if (active.length) {
      await connection.rollback();
      return;
    }

    // insert a new row as the user has completed his action for the last row
    await connection.query(`INSERT INTO trades(state, user_id) VALUES (1, 1)`);

    await connection.commit();
  } catch (err) {
    await connection.rollback();
  } finally {
    connection.release();
  }
```

Similar code is leaving me with a `ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT`.

I've though about just combining the two queries into one but inbetween the two queries there is something running onwhich my second query depends. Which leaves me with no other option (I think?).

Comment: `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is a pretty clunky way of doing this. Can't you just have a `UNIQUE` constraint that prevents duplication?

Comment: @tadman how would I apply a `UNIQUE` constraint on a dataset where I need to match both the `user_id` and `state`? A user may have multiple rows, and so may multiple rows have the same state.

Comment: You can have a `UNIQUE` index on `user_id, state` and it will mean you can't have more than one record with those two specific values. If you do need multiple rows (same state? different state?) then you may need another column in the mix.

Comment: @tadman there could indeed be cases where both the `user_id` and the `state` are shared. I would need another row to use as another unique index? It's definitely an interesting approach and might just work perfectly fine. I didn't even think about unique columns. Thanks for your input (:

Comment: Please provide a list of SQLs of two intertwined connections.  I am lost in the awaits and why you seem to need getConnection in one case but not the other.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we know what constraints do or do not exist via `PRIMARY KEY`, etc.

Comment: @RickJames it's all pseudo but there's only one primary key which is id which has `auto increment`. All other values have nothing special to them. Also I'm having trouble to understand what you mean by needing a connection in one case but not the other? Edit: I see now, I wrongly put database instead of connection. In reality this is not the case and I have changed it.

Comment: @ViziousDeveloper - In _most_ applications, there is exactly one "connection" to the database, and it is reused again and again.  And the queries are done synchronously; no multi-threading.  Trying to do database work in the background is a recipe for disaster (usually).

Comment: @RickJames Sorry, turns out you where right. I was performing the query on another connection.. this literally had me stuck for hours. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: @RickJames I'm using a pool because I've always thought it was the best to do as it would be giving a better performance and the usage doesn't differ that much from one persistent connection.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql Row-level locking working with "FOR UPDATE", Which means it will lock the entire row of table until you update the row, So in your case you are inserting new row and not updated.

Try with below code, It will work

```
 const [active] = await connection.query(`SELECT * FROM trades
              WHERE user_id = 1 AND state = 1 FOR UPDATE`);
 await database.query(`INSERT INTO trades(state, user_id) VALUES (1, 1)`);
 await database.query(`UPDATE trades SET updated_at=now() where user_id = 1 AND state = 1`);
await connection.commit();
```

Comment: I think the row is locked until `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.  And the `FOR UPDATE` locks _in anticipation of_ `UPDATE` or `DELETE` or anything else that it does not want to change in the meantime.